# Keycloak business attributes/context based access control/authorization

Tags: authorization, keycloak, abac

I am looking for support of resource attribute authorization in Keycloak.

I have a REST service which takes a datamodel (in JSON format) as body. Based on certain attribute of this Json, I want to deny or allow the request.

I know I can put my validation or kind of custom authorization logic as a layer, but I am looking if Keycloak provides any out of the box support for it like CBAC or Resource ABAC?

Comment: Any help here please?